# Вывод текста в зависимости от юрл страницы

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста написать код на php который поможет решить след задачу

если юрл страницы "https://site.com/ru/ivanofrankovsk/" вывести текст "с доставкой в Ивано Франковск"

у меня есть примерно 50 страниц
хочу добавить подзаголовок в зависимости от области
вручную не могу сделать так как использую глобальный шаблон для дублирования лендинга на все регионы

такой код не работает

```
<?php
if( is_page("https://site/ru/rovno/") ) {
    echo "Доставка в Ровно";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо делать проверку по урлу страницы. Это очень плохая практика. У вас есть глобальный массив `$_GET`. Туда передаются все GET-параметры, указанные в URL. По этим параметрам и проверяйте